# Excluding a point in double integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have a double integral as below
$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y=-\infty, y\neq x}^{\infty} f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy$$
 is this equal to 
$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy$$
or is it equal to
$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy-\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)\,dx$$
Thanks.

Comment: what are your thoughts? do you have any reason to believe one or the other?

Comment: Imagine that $x$ has "units" (e.g. length). Does the last formula respect those units?

Comment: $y=x$ is not a point, it is a line.

Answer (score 2):

The diagonal $x=y$ that you're excluding has *zero measure* under $dxdy$, so excluding it will not change the value of the intergal, nor whether it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You may write

$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y=-\infty, y\neq x}^{\infty} f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy
\\=\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy-\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y=x}^{x} f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy.$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that an integral is the summation of MANY infinitesimal slices.

Taking out the slices that result in $y=x$ will have no effect.

---

We can also say that the set has zero measure.

So it is equal to the $\displaystyle \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy$